# Filter large CSV files

Tags: powershell, csv, out-of-memory

I have some large CSV files (500MB+) with identical headers and I would like to merge it into a consolidated file after filtering for machine type = workstations. How do I filter with a particular column header "machine_type" as "workstations".  The below code works but creates CSV file with too many row data. Appreciate help. The `Import-Csv` gives me "System.OutofMemoryException' exception.

```
$inputFolder = c:\change\imput
$outputFile  = 'C:\Change\filtered.csv'

$writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter ($outputFile, $false)

Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -File | Where-Object {
$_.Extension -eq '.csv'
} | ForEach-Object {
  $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader ($_.FullName)
  if (-not $headerWritten) {
    # copy header line to output file once
    $writer.WriteLine($reader.ReadLine())
    $headerWritten = $true
  } else {
    # discard header line
    $reader.ReadLine()
  }

  while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
    $line   = $reader.ReadLine()
    $fields = $line -split ','
    #if ($line -match 'Workstation' ) {  
      $writer.WriteLine($line)
    #}
  }

  $reader.Close()
  $reader.Dispose()
}

$writer.Close()
$writer.Dispose()
```

Comment: `$line -split ','` will create an array and store in `$fields`. Just use the correct index that corresponds to the data you want, e.g. `$fields[0]` or `$fields[2]`.

Comment: "Too many row data" => can you give an example of rows that shouldn't be in the output?

Comment: $line   = $reader.ReadLine()  $fields = $line -split ','  if ($fields[6] -match 'workstation' ) {  $writer.WriteLine($line)  }  }  This works but csv file are written without truncating after each csv line data with the ouput column number stretching upto "IVW". How can i make sure the  $writer.WriteLine($line) truncates to the next row.

Comment: Strange. Sounds like .ReadLine() doesn't pick up the line ending. If you read a line, and write it unaltered to the console instead of the file, is it the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

This should work without causing OOM exceptions:

```
Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -File -Filter '*.csv' |
    ForEach-Object { Import-Csv $_.FullName } |
    Where-Object { $_.machine_type -eq 'workstations' } |
    Export-Csv $outputFile -NoType
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. But still getting "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.. The csv files are around 1.8 GB in size total.

Comment: @Enigma refer to this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/learn-how-to-configure-powershell-memory/

Comment: @Matthew The pipeline should process the input one item at a time, so memory exhaustion simply shouldn't occur unless you have a pipeline step that accumulates data. I can't test right now, though. I'll take a look when I get home tonight.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The Import-Csv is between brackets. Could it be that the data accumulates there, instead of going down the pipeline? Perhaps like this (can't test right now): ```Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -File -Filter '*.csv' |
    ForEach-Object { Import-Csv $_.FullName |
    Where-Object { $_.machine_type -eq 'workstations' } |
    Export-Csv $outputFile -NoType } ```

Comment: @BertVanLandeghem AFAIK output in a `ForEach-Object` should go directly back into the pipeline. Data is accumulated by `foreach` loops and by cmdlets like `Sort-Object`, which need to compare the items they process.

Comment: @BertVanLandeghem: You can verify what Ansgar states as follows (using `%` for `ForEach-Object` for  brevity): `% { get-childitem / -rec } | % { $_; start-sleep 1 }`. This starts producing output right away, implying that `Get-ChildItem`'s output is still being streamed, and `Import-Csv` behaves the same. Note that the only reason `ForEach-Object` is needed at all here is a _bug_ in `Import-Csv` - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4473) - which has since been fixed, but only in PowerShell _Core_.

Comment: @Enigma I ran some tests and was unable to reproduce the behavior you describe. Please update your question with the modified code you were running as well as the full, unaltered error message. Also, what PowerShell version are you running? And you may want to keep an eye on memory consumption via `perfmon` or `perfmon /res`.

Comment: @Ansgar:Original code - Import-Csv (Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Change\*.csv") |  ? "Machine_Type" -eq 'Workstation' | Export-Csv -Force -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation  -path c:\change\workstation.csv .... Then i tried your code and gets me the same error : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Csv (Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Change\S ..+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], OutOfMemoryException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.OutOfMemoryException - PSVersion                      5.1.17763.592

Comment: @Enigma It's clearly not possible that my code gave you that error.

Comment: @Ansgar: Thanks for all the help but somehow when i run the code it takes more than 90% of the memory and please note.. the total csv size is 1.8GB with 54 column and 150K row entries. I am running this on a Lenovo X260 with 8GB RAM with Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

correct me if I'm wrong, but I guess that the word "Workstation" also occurs in other columns than workstation_type, so it matches those lines too?  You can use a more elaborate regex (using capture groups) for that, see the code below:

```
$inputFolder = 'c:\temp\csv'
$outputFile  = 'C:\temp\filtered.csv'

$headerWritten = $false
[regex] $csvPattern = '(?imx)^(?<name>\w+)(\s?,\s?)(?<machine_type>\w+)(\s?,\s?)(?<location>\w+)'

$writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter ($outputFile, $false)

Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -File | Where-Object {
$_.Extension -eq '.csv'
} | ForEach-Object {
  $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader ($_.FullName)
  if (-not $headerWritten) {
    # copy header line to output file once
    $writer.WriteLine($reader.ReadLine())
    $headerWritten = $true
  } else {
    # discard header line
    $reader.ReadLine()
  }

  while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
    $line   = $reader.ReadLine()

    if ($csvPattern.Match($line).Groups.Item('machine_type').value -eq 'WorkStation' ) {  
        if ($line -match 'Workstation' ){
      $writer.WriteLine($line)
    }
  }

  $reader.Close()
  $reader.Dispose()
}

$writer.Close()
$writer.Dispose()
```

Comment: Hi Bert.. the "workstation" type will be only available in Machine_type column. Rest will be the machine spec and other details.I have run the above code. somehow not getting any result. Can you confirm " [regex] $csvPattern = '(?imx)^(?<name>\w+)(\s?,\s?)(?<machine_type>\w+)(\s?,\s?)(?<location>\w+)'" will it check for "workstation" on all column data??

Comment: The regex is built for a csv having 3 columns, separated by ',' and removing whitespace. In it, there are 3 named capture groups 'name', 'machine_type' and 'location'.  You'll have to adust the regex to correspond to the columns in your imported files. In the If, the code checks if the value of the capture group 'machine_type' is 'workstation'.  The easiest way to build and validate your regex against some sample data, is to use an online visual tool.  I use https://regex101.com/, but there probably are lots of others. It will also show you the concept of the named capture groups.